# Java calendar in different time zone gives different values for same time

Tags: java, date, calendar, timezone

Hi in the below piece of code i am getting the output as 9 and 10 , Why is that happening ?  Even though the calendars are of different time zones we are passing the same date to set the time . As far as I know the the time is calculated from the epoch as a relative value , so this relative value should be same no matter what is the time zone

I am facing a similar problem with my DB in one time zone and Server in another.

```
Date date = new Date ();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"),Locale.US);
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c1.setTime(date);
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    System.out.println(c1.get(Calendar.HOUR));
```

Comment: Is the time in Los Angeles right now the same where you live?  Is it the same in Greenwich?  From wiki *"A time zone is a region on Earth that has a uniform standard time...Most of the time zones on land are offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) by a whole number of hours (UTC−12 to UTC+14), but a few are offset by 30 or 45 minutes. Some higher latitude countries use daylight saving time for part of the year, typically by changing clocks by an hour.*"

Comment: Hi Thanks for your time, But Please not that I am setting the same time to the Calender instance and even after setting the sane time to the calendar instances , they are returning different values, thats where my confusion is

Comment: Yes but you're setting the 'same time' in two different time zones, that's what everyone is getting at. 10am in GMT != 10am in PST.

Answer (score 2):

when you pass in the date, its UTC timestamp is taken (so number of milliseconds since 01-01-1970 in GMT+0), you then set both calendars to that same time, and ask what hour it is.

obviously the hour is going to be different in different time zones - the L.A time zone and the time zone for the computer you run the code on, even though they have been initialized with the exact same UTC time.